# C# Rect class y axis not created correctly

Tags: c#, silverlight, geometry, geocoding

I am creating a Rect in C# with two points. These points are actually Geographical bounds. The problem I am having is what when I create the rectangle the y axis is flipped.

For example say my data is `west="5.42194487004" south="46.407494" east="17.166386" north="55.056664"`

I pass that into `Rect geoBounds = new Rect(new Point(west, north),new Point(east, south));`

The Rectangle that is created has the following properties

```
    Bottom  55.056664          double
    Height  7.781945           double
    IsEmpty false              bool
    Left    5.864166           double
    Right   15.038887000000003 double
    Top     47.274719          double
    Width   9.1747210000000017 double
    X       5.864166           double
    Y       47.274719          double
```

The Y axis is flipped. I have triple checked that the data being fed into the call is correct. What is wrong? Also I know that I did not supply much code but did not feel any more was needed. Will provide more if needed.

Comment: Which Point and Rect (in what namespace) are you using?

Comment: `System.Windows.Rect` and `System.Windows.Point`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinate system has 0,0 at the top left of the screen, with Y increasing in the downward direction. You can see this at the example page for the `Rect.Bottom` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect.bottom.aspx

Note on that page this comment:

```
// Bottom property gets the y-axis value of the bottom of the rectangle.  
// For this rectangle the value is 55.
rectInfo = rectInfo + "Bottom: " + myRectangle.Bottom;
```

and this one:

```
// Top property gets the y-axis position of the top of the rectangle which is  
// equivalent to getting the rectangle's Y property. 
// For this rectangle the value is 5.
rectInfo = rectInfo + "| Top: " + myRectangle.Top;
```

This is further supported by the explicit constructor for `Rect`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587929%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Note that `x` and `y` describe the top left corner, where width extends that in the rightward direction and height extends downwards.

Comment: This helps understand more but my code draws from the Top,Left,Right,Bottom values of that rectangle to be what the bounds are. Is there anyway to manually set these values?

Comment: Not if you're using the C# `Rect` to do it. You could create your own class, or just invert your coordinate system's y value to match screen coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rect geoBounds = new Rect(west, north, (east - west), (north - south));
```

Comment: This seems to come up with the correct Top but the Bottom is now even greater.

Comment: Have you tried: Rect geoBounds = new Rect(new Point(west, south),new Point(east, north)); ?